# PHP: Request the values of a HTML form drop down list

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a HTML form which is using a simple PHP `mail()` script to send its contents to an email address. I have just implemented a drop down list:

```
<select name="event">
  <option name="event1" value="event1">Event 1</option>
  <option name="event2" value="event2">Event 2</option>
  <option name="event3" value="event3">Event 3</option>  
</select>
```

But am struggling to find a way to send the chosen item via mail()

I have tried using the name of the select element:

```
$event= $_REQUEST['event'] ;
```

and the names of the option elements:

```
$event1= $_REQUEST['event1'] ;
$event2= $_REQUEST['event2'] ;
$event3= $_REQUEST['event3'] ;
```

But these dont seem to work for me. Does anyone know of the correct way to retrieve and send info via the selector list? Thanks

Comment: select only has a name not the options

Comment: `$event = $_REQUEST['event'];` should work, I don't know why it isn't working for you. Is there any more information you can provide?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff The answers below are correct. It seems it wasnt working for me as I had names for both the select and option elements at the same time - doesnt seem to like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this for your html form:

```
<select name="event">
 <option value="event1">Event 1</option>
 <option value="event2">Event 2</option>
 <option value="event3">Event 3</option>
</select>
```

And use this on your php page that your form submits to:

```
$event = $_POST['event']
```

or

```
$event = $_GET['event']
```

Answer (score 1):

Each option element does not get its own name, just a value.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6

Remove the `name` attribute from your option elements:

```
<select name="event">
  <option value="event1">Event 1</option>
  <option value="event2">Event 2</option>
  <option value="event3">Event 3</option>  
</select>
```

And depending on the method (`post` or `get`) your form element is using, you should use either:

```
$event = $_POST["event"];
```

or

```
$event = $_GET["event"];
```

Don't forget to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if saving to a database or printing back to the user in addition to using mail().