# How to send a list item value in a form with get or post request?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to submit list value using form, what is the proper way??
I have a list which is dynamically generated this is only a static list.
So how do I send a particular list value which is clicked ?
It can be accomplished by using separate name for each list,but i do not want to do that as my list is dynamically generated and I have to catch its value from a number of list items.   There is a solution for a similar type of problem for dropdown list. link-[PHP: Request the values of a HTML form drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944120/php-request-the-values-of-a-html-form-drop-down-list)

```
<form action="" id="form-id" method="get">
<ol name="test">
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();">
<li>
<input type="hidden"  value="testvalue">  //list value 1 
Coffee
</li>
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();">
<li>
<input type="hidden"  value="testvalue1">  //list value 2
Tea
</li>
</a>
</ol>
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_GET['test']))
 echo $_GET['test'];
?>
```

Comment: The input element MUST have a name

Comment: I know that, I am asking if there is any way to accomplish this?

Comment: then why do the text fields not have names?

Comment: use onclick on li and update a hidden param in form on clicking it :)

Comment: @ChakradharVyza  how to send a hidden param in form on clicking it? I am already using onclick,question is how to send list value different for each item.

Comment: if u have a submit button all input vars ll be send... u can use jquery .submit function if u dont want a button

Comment: have you seen this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071587/php-pass-array-through-post"?

Comment: @brandelizer please read the problem,using onclick() form can be submitted too.

Comment: @CodeDemon thnx i will try this ,it is nearer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your exact requirements here but I think this might be what you are looking for?

```
    <form action="" id="form-id" method="get">
        <h1>Hidden values</h1>
        <ol name="test">
            <li><input type="hidden" value="testvalue">Cofee</li>
            <li><input type="hidden" value="testvalue1">Tea</li>
        </ol>
        <input type='hidden' id='test' name='test' />
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['test'] ) ){
                echo 'Test: '.$_GET['test'];
            }
        ?>
    </form> 
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            var form=document.getElementById('form-id');
            var col=form.querySelectorAll('li');
            for( var n in col ) if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ){
                col[n].onclick=function(e){
                    document.getElementById('test').value=this.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"]')[0].value;
                    form.submit();
                };
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: thnx this is the solution i am looking for.