# PHP Contact Form with dropdown

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to figure this out for several days and cannot! I have searched and tried different codes, some javascript, some php, etc. I like the one I am using, I just need to figure out WHAT line of code to put in my PHP file.

Contact form has 4 fields. Upon submit, the form is emailed to me.
While testing it, I receive the email with only 3 of the fields... The one I am not receiving is "users choice selected from dropdown box".

I found another thread almost identical to mine (on this site) and **I tried what was suggested, but it did not work for me, and I don't know why.**  Here is the link to the thread by another user:  [PHP: Request the values of a HTML form drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944120/php-request-the-values-of-a-html-form-drop-down-list)

**HTML**

```
<select size="1" name="drop_down">
    <option value="Shows">Shows</option>
    <option value="Education">Education</option>
    <option value="Coaching">Coaching</option>
    <option value="Regional Convention Assistance">Regional Convention Assistance</option>
    <option value="Quartet Workshop: Vivapalooza!">Quartet Workshop: Vivapalooza!</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'yecartdotcom@yahoo.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Viva! Contact Form '; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."<br>";
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: you dont use `$_POST['drop_down']`in your code

Comment: also add: $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Drop Down: ".nl2br($_POST["drop_down"])."<br>";

Comment: I added the code, and and tested it. Now I'm not receiving an email at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply miss to use drop down in your code.

Update like below :-

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'myemail.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Contact Form '; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Drop Down: ".nl2br($_POST["drop_down"])."<br>";
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: I copy/pasted the code you provided, re-uploaded the php file and now I am not receiving an email at all once I send form. I am so confused. When I click SEND, it takes me to the "thank you page" as if it sent. The email never comes now.

Comment: Email must come if you are getting it earlier. I have just added your missing drop down code and nothing else. It will not effect your mail function at all. Please wait for some time and check in your spam folder as well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll wait a bit.

Comment: Yes please let me know when it arrives.

Comment: Still nothing. I have received other email though, but nothing from this form since adding that line of code. I went through this same thing for so many hours last night and I don't understand WHY adding that 1 line makes it not arrive via email. :(

Comment: don't worry, we will resolve it. Please let me know which value you are selecting in drop down and before email code, check with echo $_POST["drop_down"]; die; And also remove nl2br function from $_POST["drop_down"]

Comment: Make it like $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Drop Down: ".$_POST["drop_down"]."<br>";

Comment: I changed code to $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Drop Down: ".$_POST["drop_down"]."<br>";

Comment: I don't understand the echo part... What code do I put where with the echo? Still no email without the echo in there.

Comment: no no I am asking you to debug $_POST["drop_down"] before using in email.

Comment: Because if no value coming in $_POST["drop_down"] then nl2br can create issue and no email will go.

Comment: I don't know how to do your request "debug"

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! YOU ARE AWESOME, MY FRIEND!